# Session loses its data with Carrierwave multi files upload using jquery file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

Simply I've a model called `Estate` which `has many :images` (`Image model`) and
I'm using `CarrierWave` & `jQueryFileUpload` to handle these in Estate `New/Edit` forms.

While creating new estate, and upload an image, jQueryFileUpload is doing that using AJAX request, so I make all uploaded images paths be stored in a session array then I use this array in `create` or `update` actions to save the images from `tmp` directory to actual directory.

This works fine with me, but The problem is when I've selected more than one photo at a time, session array store only last selected image, and not all images be pushed to the session array except the last one.

```
  def images_url_list
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    session[:cached_images_paths] << @image.image_file.current_path
  end
```

I've debugged this action and I found that if I selected 5 images at a time, images_url_list action is fired 5 times, so say that I upload an image called "path0" then I uploaded 5 images which paths called ["path1","path2","path3","path4","path5"] and the session already has a path called "path0", first time after uploading first image the session will be ["path0", "path1"], second time ["path0","path2"] and so on until last image which is path5.

So the final count of image paths is only 2 rather than 6 image paths.

Can anyone tell me what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the multi-request and the session save.
In my case using a similar environment, only the last uploaded file was saved. I couldn't make it work adding it in a filesUploaded array, so I though about an alternative solution.

A good approach might be:

- Generate a session upload hash and store it for each uploaded file on the upload listener
- Use it to identify the uploaded files after the multi-upload is finished